# creating a associative array/hash in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form with different groups of checks boxes and trying to pass all the selected values into an array then pass that data into a ajax request.

```
$('#accessoriesOptions input').each(function(index, value){
    if($(this).attr('checked') ){
        var newItem =[];
        var obj = {};
        obj[$(this).attr('value')] = $(this).attr('name'); //I have an hash table with the key-value
        wizard.searchArray.push(obj);
    }            
})

$.ajax({
   data : wizard.searchArray
})
```

I get a wizard.searchArray like :

```
   [0] = {'acc_1' : 'vase'},
   [1] = {'acc_3' : 'ceramic'}
```

I need to create a key-value as I use the key to work out which part of the filtering to use.

**The problem**

When I do the ajax request, from firebug I see the request as :

/wizard-demo/?undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case just push add the properties to the `obj` and use it directly, that's the pair that'll get serialized property when used as the `data` property, like this:

```
var obj = {};
$('#accessoriesOptions input').each(function(index, value){
    if(this.checked){
        obj[this.value] = this.name;
    }            
})

$.ajax({
   data : obj
});
```

Though this is backwards from a normal `<form>` submission, if that's what you want it's this instead:

```
obj[this.name] = this.value;
```

If you wanted to send the entire form, there's a much shorter/built-in [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method for this:

```
$.ajax({
   data : $("#accessoriesForm").serialize()
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip on serialize! Planning to use this instead!